# Longer term accommodation proof for schengen visa application (Germany)

Tags: schengen, germany, schengen-visas

I intend to pursue an internship in Germany for the summer of 2020, approx (82 days) but my employer doesn't provide me accommodation.

Can I show a booking from booking.com as a proof of accomodation even though the number of days is quite high so it will be super expensive than if i look for a shared flat.

I have my bank statements in place to show for the proof of funds but a hotel booking for 80 days is still super expensive for my parents income whom i have added as my sponsors.

Looking for a shared flat has been extremely difficult online for me but I don't want to create any delays in my visa application (due to a horrible experience in the past) and I am quite sure that I will be able to find a shared accommodation by the time I reach there or book a hotel/hostel for a week and find a shared accomodation there itself in person.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith I think the question is very clear which is asked in the second paragraph

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a country tag. We need to know where you are, and what embassy you're talking to.

Comment: I can't promise it'll work for schengen, but every time I've had to show proof of accommodation for a visa application I've used booking.com but made sure I made a booking at a hotel that had no deposit and free cancellation. That way once the visa is granted I can cancel it and actually sort out my accommodation properly.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, why to you believe that **proof of accomodation** must be supplied at all (i. e. is mandatory) when making the application?

The application form for a D-Visa states that you you should give the address ***if known*** (for the C-Visa application, this not stated that clearly).

---

D-Visa Application form (December 2019) Question 6:

> Vorgesehener Aufenthaltsort in der Bundesrepublik Deutschland **Intended place of stay in Germany**
>
> - Straße, Hausnummer (*sofern bekannt*) **Street, number (*if known*)**
> - Postleitzahl, Ort **Postcode, place**
>
> Wie werden Sie untergebracht sein? **How will you be accommodated?**
>
> - Einzelzimmer **Single room**
> - Wohnung mit Zimmern **Apartment with rooms**
> - Sammelunterkunft **Collective accommodation**
> - Sonstiges (bitte erläutern): **Other (please specify):**

Both applications require to to confirm, in different ways, that the information is given **to best of his or her knowledge and belief**:

> - **C-Visa**: I declare that to the best of my knowledge all particulars supplied by me are correct and complete.
> - **D-Visa**: The applicant is obliged to provide all information to the best of his or her knowledge and belief.

The wording states clearly what you **intend** to look for, not what you have achived. If someone has done this for you in Germany, then you can give that address as proof.

So if you don't have that proof, leave it blank.

You can also address this in a short covering letter,  making it clear what your intentions are - thus avoiding any misunderstandings.

No one expects, when making a application, that you have a legally binding contract for a long term accommodation, just as they don't require you to have a fully paid return ticket.

---

> Looking for a shared flat has been extremely difficult online for me ... and I am quite sure that I will be able to find a shared accommodation by the time I reach there or book a hotel/hostel for a week and find a shared accomodation there itself in person.

This attitude is completely reasonable and realistic.

Upon arrival (where the conditions for entry will be checked), showing that you have an accommodation for the first week is, however, advised.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can show your booking as proof of accommodation from booking.com 
Even I had an experience when I applied to Singapore Visa. I had booked a hotel accommodation via booking.com but didn't pay the amount. I used it just to show for the purpose of applying to a visa. I got my visa, but when I appeared in immigration check at the airport, the immigration officer asked me to show the hotel accommodation details to verify. I had given my smartphone and showed him my booking details and he checked whether my name was there in the booking or not. But when you book via booking.com, don't pay the amount, check for the hotels which don't require you to pay before. And one more thing is check for hostels and also try the Couchsurfing app. It will be really helpful for you.